# How to implement scoped storage to pick video from Gallery and send it to another Activity on Android 10

Tags: android, android-studio, android-10.0, android-external-storage, scoped-storage

In my app i have 2 buttons one to open camera and record video and second one to select video from Gallery , then i send the video to another activity using intent . It is working fine on all android versions except android 10

```
private void openVideoCapture() {
        String[] perms = {Manifest.permission.CAMERA};
        if (EasyPermissions.hasPermissions(this, perms)) {
            final int durationLimit = 600;
            Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE);
            intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_DURATION_LIMIT, durationLimit);
            startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_VIDEO_TRIMMER);
        } else {
            // Do not have permissions, request them now
            EasyPermissions.requestPermissions(this, getString(R.string.permission_camera), 123, perms);
        }

    }
    @AfterPermissionGranted(124)
    private void pickFromGallery() {
        String[] perms = {Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE};
        if (EasyPermissions.hasPermissions(this, perms)) {
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setTypeAndNormalize("video/*");
            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
            startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, getString(R.string.label_select_video)), REQUEST_VIDEO_TRIMMER);
        } else {
            EasyPermissions.requestPermissions(this, getString(R.string.permission_read_storage_rationale), 124, perms);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            if (requestCode == REQUEST_VIDEO_TRIMMER) {
                final Uri selectedUri = data.getData();
                if (selectedUri != null) {
                      startTrimActivity(selectedUri);
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, R.string.toast_cannot_retrieve_selected_video, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private void startTrimActivity(@NonNull Uri uri) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, TrimmerActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra(EXTRA_VIDEO_PATH, FileUtils.getPath(this, uri));
        startActivity(intent);
    }
```

Comment: `intent.putExtra(EXTRA_VIDEO_PATH, FileUtils.getPath(this, uri));` Dont try to get a path from an uri. Use the uri directly. Convert your code to use it like: `intent.putExtra(EXTRA_VIDEO_PATH, uri.toString());`.

Comment: Ideally, this would be all one activity, not two, perhaps using fragments for the different screen contents. If you need two activities, pass the `Uri` as a `Uri` from one activity to the next, with permission (e.g., `Intent intent = new Intent(this, TrimmerActivity.class).setData(uri).addPermission(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION)`).

Comment: @blackapps i need the path to be used on FFmpeg command

Comment: If you have a path you can not use it as you have seen. Add legacyExternalStorage true to manifest to continue until 11.

Comment: @blackapps put legacyExternalStorage true but it is still not working on Android 10 . It works only when i reduce targetsdkversion to 28

Comment: WHAT exactly is not working? If you dont tell we will not know.

Comment: @blackapps ffmpeg library is not working

Comment: If you do not give better info there is nobody who can help you.